# Using multiple queries to avoid the NOT keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this first set of lines, without the NOT keyword:

```
insert into temptable 
    (select value1, count(value1), value2, count(value2) 
        from originaltable group by value1, value2)
delete from temptable where value1=1 and value2=1 
delete from temptable where value1=0 and value2=1 
select * from temptable
```

and this second query.

```
select value1, count(value1), value2, count(value2) from originaltable 
    where not (value1=1 and value2=1)
      and not (value1=0 and value2=1)
    group by value1, value2
```

Could there be instances wherein the first set of queries is faster or more desirable than the second? I think the first set of queries is faster when there are a lot of data in originaltable and temptable is indexed. I think so because for the first choice, there will be no need to compare using the NOT keyword.

Am I even correct in saying that the NOT keyword can cause query 2 to be slower?

Comment: There is no reason for the second query to be slower. If it is slower, than please provide results, sample data and number of records used for test. There is nothing wrong with using NOT clause.

Comment: The first approach is more likely to be faster because there are much fewer records in the temptable. But it is impossible to be precise without far more information such as table and index definitions, the execution plan(s), knowing if your statistics and indexes are fresh or stale etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, you were wrong**

### Firstly

If no data exists in your originaltable, the first queries may faster than the second.

### Secondly

There are datas in your originaltable.

If there is an index of value1 and value2 on originaltable, second query will be more faster than the first.

If there is an index of value1 and value2 on temptable, the first query will be more slower than the second one.

### Thirdly

`NOT` is a logic operation takes same time as `=`,`<>`,etc.

### Analyze without index:

```
insert into temptable --need at least one tablescan and an aggregation operation.log file will be written
(select value1, count(value1), value2, count(value2) 
    from originaltable group by value1, value2)
delete from temptable where value1=1 and value2=1 --need one tablescan, log file will be written 
delete from temptable where value1=0 and value2=1 --need one tablescan, log file will be written 
select * from temptable --one tablescan
```

Your first queries need four tablescan operations and one aggregation at least, and more worse thing is your queries need to write log file, that's really slow operation to all DBMS.

Your second query only need one tablescan operation and one aggregation, all the other operations of your first queries can only wast time.

### Analyze with index:

If you have index on temptable, you may safe some time of finding the rows need to be deleted, but you will add more time to rebuild indexes. More data you have more time need to spent on rebuild indexes.

If you have index on originaltable, you can get benefit from saving time with index scan directly.

By the way, you should add an `truncate table` operation before first queries.